# Ubuntu 14.04 - How to update to the latest version of PHP in order to run WordPress 5.4.1

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, wordpress

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to use the latest version of WordPress v5.4.1.

When trying to run my WordPress site, I'm receiving the error:

```
Your server is running PHP version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 but WordPress 5.4.1 requires at least 5.6.20.
```

Can people pls assist on how to update my PHP version and PHP-MySQL to 5.6.20 or to the latest stable version of PHP and PHP-MySQL?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version  I would be afraid to try to upgrade PHP on a version of Ubuntu that is beyond its end of life (which 14.04 is.)  Since it might want to upgrade the entire system.  If you are still on 14.04, it is probably for a reason.

Comment: @StephenDaddona - sorry, are you saying then that I shouldn't attempt to update PHP to atleast PHP 5.6.20 as I don't want to break my 14.04 setup?

Comment: I would be afraid of it, myself, but I'm not a guru at all.  If I were going to try to install an upgrade, I would boot from a LIVE disk and run a complete backup first.  Then I could at least restore the system if I break it.  I had to do that three days ago when I tried to deinstall ecryptfs on my 14.04 LTS machine.  I like to use Redo backup, which I have burned to a CD.

Comment: I've  been doing some searching and I found this.  Maybe it will help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Comment: Here is another good one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get

Comment: Also, be sure to back up your mySQL database first in case you mess that up.  Look at the mysqldump command for how to do that.  I had to restore mine because the restore of the system put my database in a three-day-old state, since my system backup was three days old.  I have a script that I run daily, via cron, to back up my database.

Comment: @StephenDaddona - appreciate all your help and links. Will take a look.